# What's deadlock in programming?

Tags: java, oop, deadlock

What is deadlock in programming Object Oriented ?

I had knew deadlock in transaction of Database Systems. But in programming I'm not clear. 
I want to know when deadlock occur and how to resolve it.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe [wikipedia - deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) can help you!

Comment: This is a pretty good explanation of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143873/how-to-explain-the-deadlock-better

Answer (score 1):

A deadlock is when you have two or more processes that are each waiting for the other to finish. When this happens, neither one can continue and the program essentially stalls.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic example here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html

well documented.

but, a deadlock occurs when you wait for a object to be freed but that condition is never achieved.