# Why Does FDT 5.5 Hang When I Import A Project?

Tags: eclipse, import, fdt

When importing a FDT 5.0 project into FDT 5.5, the progress bar in main dialog stalls just short of the end. The progress indicator on main workspace window (bottom right) is stuck on "refreshing workspace" or 'importing core.prefs'.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in FDT 5.5.0 and a hotfix is due imminently. You can follow the progress on JIRA [here](http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-2741). When the update is available, FDT will notify you. You can also keep an eye on the [FDT's twitter account](https://twitter.com/#!/fdt5) or [FDT's blog](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/blog/).

The problem was due to a [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512/what-is-a-deadlock) when reading the preferences of your project. That is why it was hanging.