# Implementing a Generic Singleton Factory in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

I am currently working on a project where I have to create several singleton instances of different types. I know that creating singletons for each type can be a bit tedious and error-prone, so I wanted to implement a generic singleton factory in C#. However, I am a bit unsure about the best way to accomplish this task.

The objective is to have a method which can create a singleton instance of any given type. Here is a simple code that I have so far:

```
public class SingletonFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> instances = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        if (!instances.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            instances[typeof(T)] = new T();
        }
        return (T)instances[typeof(T)];
    }
}
```

This is a minimalist version, and I understand that it does not take into account things like thread safety and disposing.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I enhance the above code to make it thread-safe?
2. Is there any better approach to implement this pattern which would also take into account the disposal of instances when they are no longer needed?
3. Is there a way to make this pattern work if the class that needs to
   be instantiated has some parameters in its constructor?

I appreciate any help or advice that you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Your DI container should do this as close to the root as possible. Use middleware to create your singletons.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Thread safety.** What prevents you from just wrapping all `GetInstance` code into a `lock` operator block, locking `instances`? If you don't want a [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34520/20426120), you could use `Monitor` directly:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

// ...

private const int timeout = 1000;  // Timeout for acquiring a lock in milliseconds

// Standard constructor not necessary, see next paragraph
public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
{
  bool lockTaken;
  Monitor.TryEnter(instances, timeout, ref lockTaken);

  if (lockTaken) {
    try {
      // Singleton factory code
    }
    finally { Monitor.Exit(instances); }
  } else {
    throw new SystemException(/* "Go wait I'm busy" */ "Lock timeout expired.");
  }
}
```

(Why I said "directly"? A `lock` operator is translated into a `Monitor.Enter` call by the compiler.)

2. **Passing parameters to constructor.** Reflection helps you. Don't forget to add an `object[]` parameter to `GetInstance` called `parameters` or whatever you want.

```cs
instances[typeof(T)] = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameters);  // Instead of "new T()"
```

3. **Disposal.** To be disposed properly, a class should either have a destructor or implement `IDisposable`. If it has destructor, calling it won't be your work but the garbage collector's. In case it implements `IDisposable`, only the client code knows when to call `Dispose`, so the right way to handle that would be creating a method like this:

```cs
public static void DisposeInstance<T>() where T : class {
  if (!instances.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) {
    throw new ArgumentException("Instance not found");
  }

  var interfaces = typeof(T).FindInterfaces(((type, criteria) => type == typeof(IDisposable)), null);
  if (interfaces.Length == 0) {
    throw new ArgumentException("Specified instance does not implement IDisposable");
  }

  typeof(T).InvokeMember("Dispose", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instances[typeof(T)], new object?[] { });
}
```

4. **Exceptions.** The constructor of `T` can easily throw an exception. `Dispose` (in an awfully designed class) can throw one, too. So it'd be nice to wrap both methods into a `try` block with a `catch` like this:

```cs
catch (Exception ex) {
  throw new ApplicationException(
    "Constructor threw an exception. See inner exception for details.", /* Or "Method \"Dispose\" threw an exception" */
    ex);
}
```